# MVC 6 Tag Helpers and foreach

Tags: collections, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

What would I give to asp-for property of a label tag helper in order to display items from a collection. The code below generates a compilation error.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <label asp-for="item.BookingCode"></label>
}
```

Comment: what is error and,in model i think you have collection of same item and all items will contain same attribute name for same value.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was actually looking for a way to display values, but apparently MVC6 does not have tag helper for this yet. The error is that there is no "item" in scope, which makes sense because Model.item does not exist.

Comment: @ConvertToInt32 - actually even if I put <label> outside for foreach, I still don't get what should be in asp-for. My model is IEnumerable<>.

Comment: <label name="BookingCode">@item.BookingCode</label> i think it could be like that i have not met  with mvc 6 actually

Comment: This would bring me value of item.BookingCode using default ToString(), i.e. not properly formatted

Comment: Instead of using IEnumerable<T> as your model try IList<T>.

Comment: @Jimi - you mean "for" instead of "foreach"? It works perfectly if I access via ElementAt(i).BookingCode

Comment: You said your model is IEnumerable<>. Switch it to IList<> like adding '.ToList<>()' at the end, in code behind.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The `@` character escapes the default model lambda code. Therefore you can type:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <label asp-for="@item.BookingCode"></label>
}
```

Comment: In 1.0.0-rc1-update1 the above code simply prints "BookingCode" text instead of the actual value of the BookingCode property. 
Any other solutions?

Comment: Since this is for a label element the asp-for defaults to the property name and not the value of BookingCode. Use @item.BookingCode with no element to see the value.

Comment: Tag helper for `<label>` will not be that important here. But if you wan to use it, as @JoelCunningham stated, use `<label asp-for="@item.BookingCode">@item.BookingCode</label>` asp-for value will display the heading as a property name and @item.BookingCode inside <label ...>...</label> will display the value of @item.BookingCode.

Answer (score -4):

I Have a simple way to do a list and show properties of it.

```
List<string> razones = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in _context.Reason)
{
    razones.Add (item.Description);
}
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(razones.Count);
```