# asp-for in checkbox throws and error in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

Here i have used two checkbox

```
<label asp-for="SendReport" class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" asp-for="SendReport" />Send Report</label><br>
<label asp-for="SendInvoice" class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" asp-for="SendInvoice" />Send Invoice</label><br>
```

and data type for both checboc i.e `asp-for="SendReport" and asp-for="SendInvoice"` is `bit`.
Now the problem is that when ever i try to load the page its throws error as below

```
Unexpected 'asp-for' expression result type 'System.Nullable`1[[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]' for <input>. 'asp-for' must be of type 'System.Boolean' or 'System.String' that can be parsed as a 'System.Boolean' if 'type' is 'checkbox'.<br>
```

Any help will be heartly thankful. Thank you

Comment: Is there any reason you bind a `bit field` to `checkbox`? `checkbox` is binded by `true` or `false`, how did you decide when to check the `checkbox` by `bit`? What is the value for `bit field`?

Answer (score 8):

> When happened use **bit** *datatype*  for reparent `true, false` but **column allow null checked**

You can fixed by two way

**First**:  Set Not Allow null or remove `?` in filed

**Example:**

```
public bool? SendReport {get; set; } 
// change to below code 
public bool SendReport {get; set; }
```

**Second:** You can use normal html tag for checkbox input

```
<input type="checkbox" id="SendReport" name="SendReport" @((Model.SendReport== false ? "" : "checked")) />
```

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same issue when working with EFcore.
From the database, I have:

```
namespace Project.EFCoreModels;
public partial class Account 
{
    public int AccountId {get; set;}
    public bool? HasSaleTax {get; set;}    
}
```

I want to display `HasSalesTax` as a checkbox input with asp tag helper:

```
<input type="checkbox" asp-for="HasSaleTax" class="form-control" />
```

This thows the error because the the input type checkbox does not accept nullable value. Fair enough.

To work around it, I created another partial class, same namespace, but on a different project directory (folder). This is a common pattern in .NetCore MVC when we want to add MetaData to an EFCore class.

```
namespace Project.EFCoreModels;
public partial class Account 
{         
    public bool SalesTaxInput 
    {
        get => this.HasSaleTax.GetValueOrDefault(); 
        set {this.HasSaleTax = value;} 
    }    
}
```

Then on the view, you just bind the input with the newly created prop:

```
 <input type="checkbox" asp-for="SalesTaxInput" class="form-control" />
```

Answer (score 5):

This is because `asp-for` is **always** expecting a boolean parameter when input type is **`checkbox`**, **or a string parameter that can be parsed as boolean**.

This said, having the assumption that `SendReport` and `SendInvoice` are not boolean:

> Unexpected 'asp-for' expression result type 'System.Nullable`

you will have to change these parameters into boolean parameters that will be false by default, or into string parameters that will contain `"false"` or `"true"` by default.

Answer (score 2):

> It is an issue with: `asp-for="SendReport"`. That is not valid because
>   the tag is input of type checkbox so `asp-for` is expecting a `boolean`
>   and you are sending it a something else than a boolean.

Refer this:
[Asp.net MVC putting checkbox data in a list of booleans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41511664/asp-net-mvc-putting-checkbox-data-in-a-list-of-booleans)

Comment: Specifically, a nullable `boolean` (`bool?`) is being sent

Answer (score 0):

If you use a

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SendReport, new { @class = "form-control" }}
```

it will give you a dropdown box with options

```
<select id="SendReport" name="SendReport" class="list-box tri-state"> 
    <option value="">Not Set</option>
    <option value="true">True</option>
    <option value="false">False</option>
</select>
```

at least I do, when using Bootstrap 4 and Visual Studio 2019, with .NET Core 3.1

Answer (score 0):

Anyone running into this MVC core abandon the "for"
@Html.CheckBox("tblSubCategory.Enabled",Model.tblSubCategory.Enabled.HasValue? Model.tblSubCategory.Enabled:false)

tblSubCategory is a sub model on a view,
Enabled is a nullable boolean

Answer (score 0):

Just removing ? do not work.
for me worked as i wrapped around a div claaa=checkbox

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="IsDeleted" class="control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <input asp-for="IsDeleted" class="form-check" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="IsDeleted" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```