# Get table cell value and submit to a delete function

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I have a table which displays data from my database. I want to provide a button which will delete data from a table based on the row selected. Specifically based on the value of a specific cell of that table.

I've tried wrapping a button inside a form element as an extra  element inside of each row, but this doesn't seem to work for 2 reasons. 1, it triggers the OnGet() function in my controller and 2 it doesn't seem to bind the cell data value to my 'SourceTable' property.

The following is my front-end table:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>OrderIdentifier</td>
            <td>Step Number</td>
            <td>CreateDate</td>
            <td>Step Status</td>
            <td>Source Table</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    @foreach (var order in Model.order.Steps)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@order.OrderIdenfitier</td>
            <td>@order.Name</td>
            <td>@order.CreateDate</td>
            <td>@order.StepStatus</td>
            <td>@order.SourceTable</td>

            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-dark"
                   asp-page="./OrderDetail"
                   asp-route-orderId="@order.OrderIdenfitier">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></i>
                    Details
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form method="delete">
                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" asp-for="SourceTable" />
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></i>
                        Delete
                    </button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

And on the backend, I'd like to be passing in the SourceTable cell value of whatever row the button is clicked on into this function:

```
        public IActionResult OnDelete(string SourceTable)
        {
            //Take SourceTable parameter, pass to data access layer, and delete from database. 
            return Page();
        }
```

I would like to have the value of the SourceTable cell passed to my OnDelete function, but this doesn't occur. Additionally, my 'OnGet()' function is triggered when I click my delete button, not the 'OnDelete()' function. The I form I embedded the button in has action="delete", so I would think that it would go to the OnDelete() function, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP `DELETE` method is currently [not supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-method) by `<form>` element. That's why you hit `OnGet()` in your Razor page. You are still able to use `OnPost()` for that purpose with binding form values (e.g. hidden inputs) to action method parameters.

The second issue is with your `asp-for` input tag helper. By default it evaluates its expression against `PageModel`. You can use `@` to override that behaviour, especially when you're [in a foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903972/mvc-6-tag-helpers-and-foreach). Your form then could look like this:

```html
<form method="post">
  <input type="hidden" asp-for="@order.SourceTable"/>
  <input type="submit" vaue="Delete"/>
</form>
```

and action method:

```
public IActionResult OnPost(string SourceTable)
{
    // delete record here
    return RedirectToPage();
}
```

Maybe you don't like the idea to delete records in `OnPost` handler, which you would like to reserve for some other action.Then you can use [named handler method](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods#named-handler-methods) like `OnPostDelete(string SourceTable)`. All you have to do is to add attribute `asp-page-handler="delete"` to the `<form>` element:

```html
<form asp-page-handler="delete" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" asp-for="@order.SourceTable"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Delete"/>
</form>
```

And maybe you don't like the idea of having a separate form for each row in the table. Then wrap the form around the table and use `asp-route-` prefix on each delete button to specify parameter binding:

```html
<form method="post">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <!-- ... -->
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach (var order in Model.order.Steps)
      {
        <tr>
          <!-- ... -->
          <td>
            <input type="submit" value="delete" asp-page-handler="delete" asp-route-sourcetable="@order.SourceTable" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      }
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

You can find more valuable information in artice [Introduction to Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio).

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I wasn't aware of the named handlers .net core had available. Turned out to be just what I needed.